# Why I am not getting warnings about StrictNullChecks in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, webstorm

I have the following code in typescript:

```
interface Member {
    name: string,
    age?: number
}

class Person implements Member {
    name: string;
    constructor(name: string ){
        this.name=name;
    }
}

function bar(person: Member) {
    return "Hello, " + person.name + " " + person.age;
}

let person = new Person("John");
console.log(bar(person));
```

I am supposed to get **Object is possibly 'undefined'** warning inside bar function when i declare person.age since not every Member can have age.

my typescript config looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "outDir": "./built"
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Any idea why this is not working for me? I am using WebStorm Editor!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

strictNullChecks checks that all the operations performed on a property leads to a non-null value. But in the bar function it is only printing the `person.age` regardless if it is null or undefined. If you were to say `person.age.toString()` typescript would throw a compile time error.

Answer (score 11):

Turn on `"strict": true,` in the tsconfig.json to enable this warning.

Or if you don't want all the strict options you in need:

```
"strictNullChecks": true,
"strictPropertyInitialization": true,
```

See the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) for more information

`--strictNullCheck`:

> In strict null checking mode, the null and undefined values are not in the domain of every type and are only assignable to themselves and any (the one exception being that undefined is also assignable to void).

`--strictPropertyInitialization`

> Ensure non-undefined class properties are initialized in the constructor. This option requires --strictNullChecks be enabled in order to take effect.

The second one is the one you want (but needs `strictNullChecks` to work)

Btw, as @jayasai amerineni mentions, your example shouldn't trigger this warning.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem, but I was consuming a possibly null type as a argument in a function which required a non-null parameter, so it definitely should have been throwing an error for me.

I had already turned on `strict: true` and `strictNullChecks: true` for good measure, but it only actually worked for me when I closed VSCode and reloaded it. If anyone else has this issue, makes sure to restart your code editor!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).