# Typescript not recognising | null operator

Tags: typescript

I have a problem with typescript in my project and it had started about 2 weeks and problem is that if I say my property is `string | null` typescript says its only string.

[image]

I can't find whats the problem and I don't know whats causing it. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is TypeScript not warning when setting a non-nullable value as null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60889805/why-is-typescript-not-warning-when-setting-a-non-nullable-value-as-null) and [Why I am not getting warnings about StrictNullChecks in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53740494)

Comment: @VLAZ thank you thats my answer. I have added `"strict": true` in tsconfig and worked.